# iOS Bowling Score UI Layout

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiview

I'm trying to figure out the best way to layout the view so it dynamically handles multiple screen sizes. Right now I'm looking at doing 2 labels per frame (1 per throw) and 3 for the 10th. That is a total of 21 labels to display the bowling score. That doesn't seem right and I'm not even sure if putting them all in a horizontal stack view will even properly manage this layout for multiple screens.

I have an image placeholder there now which is what I envision it to look like at the top of the app as the score fills in. Any ideas?

[image: bowling-score-screenshot]

Comment: 21 labels seems ok to me, and a horizontal `UIStackView` seems perfectly sufficient. But if you're worried about copying & pasting all of those cells in the storyboard, you can use a `UICollectionView`, but IMHO, there are two reasons *not* to do that: 1) futzing with a custom `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` can be a pain, and 2) if the number of cells never changes (as is the case here), I'd *much* rather see some duplication in the storyboard if it allows me to see *exactly* what'll be on the screen when I preview it in IB.

Comment: Or you can have the best of both worlds by creating an `@IBDesignable` view for the frame, do your layout in code, and then populating your stack view with 10 frames. Being designable means that they'll render properly in IB, and you don't have to duplicate much.